# componentDidMount getting called multiple times in redux connected component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

I have a reactjs+redux app in which app.js, the first component to be mounted is given below:

```
//all imports here
class App extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            loginState : false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user);
                if(user.displayName&&user.photoURL&&user.email)
                    this.props.dispatch(login(user.displayName, user.photoURL, user.email));
                else
                    this.props.dispatch(login(user.email.split("@")[0], "", ""));
                this.setState({
                    loginState: true
                });
            }
            else{
                this.props.dispatch(changeLoading());
            }
        });
    }
    logout = () => {
        
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signOut()
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({
                    loginState : false,
                });
                this.props.dispatch(logout());
                this.props.history.push('/login');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
    render() {
        
        return (
            <>
                <Switch>
                    {this.props.userName?(<Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        component={() => <Homepage userName={this.props.userName} />}
                    />):(<Route exact path="/" component={Loading} />)}
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Redirect to="/" />
                </Switch>
            </>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.userState.isLoggedIn,
        userName: state.userState.userName,
        email: state.userState.email,
        photoURL: state.userState.photoURL
    };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

Below is `Homepage.js`:

```
class Homepage extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("component mounted");
        this.props.dispatch(fetchPosts());
    }
    
    render(){
        console.log("Homepage reached");
        if(this.props.userName==='') return <Redirect to="/login" />
        return(
            <div className="container-fluid m-0" style={{paddingTop: '100px',paddingLeft: '0',paddingRight: '0'}}>
                <div className="row m-0">
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <Main userName={this.props.userName} />
                    <Leftside userName={this.props.userName} />
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Homepage);
```

And below is the reducer:

```
export const userState=(state={isLoading: true,isLoggedIn: false,userName: '', photoURL: ''},action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'LOGIN': {console.log("reached");return {...state,isLoading: false,isLoggedIn: true, userName: action.payload.userName, photoURL: action.payload.photoURL, email: action.payload.email}}
        case 'LOGOUT': return {...state,isLoading: false,isLoggedIn:false,userName: '',photoUrl: ''}
        case 'CHANGE': return {...state,isLoading: false}
        default: return {...state}
    }
}
```

Basically what is happening is that initially when the app opens, `this.props.userName` is empty and hence `Loading` component is loaded. Once the firebase returns the user details, they are dispatched to redux reducer. When this happens, `state.userState.userName` becomes available and `Homepage` is mounted. As expected, its `componentDidMount` method runs and posts are fetched and dispatched to the redux store( posts are stored in redux store). But then suddenly `Homepage` unmounts and mounted again and consequently, `componntDidMount` runs again. So, in total, there are two `fetchPost` requests.

I do not understand this behaviour. I have read that `componentDidMount` runs only a single time.

Please help me to remove this bug.
Thank You!

Comment: I think the problem is in Routes

component={() => <Homepage userName={this.props.userName} />}

So when your parent component re-renders it create a new Component Homepage and removes the previously mounted component.

Comment: Also the unexpected logout could be because when your backend response comes you are updating the redux fields used in your Parent component, which is re-rendering the component.

Comment: There is another problem in the project. When logout function is called, Homepage unmounts and for some reason, it unexpectedly mounts again.

Comment: @tarunjain so what might be the solution?

Comment: So instead of rendering different Routes on "/", you can have a condition inside the Container that will be render on path "/". In that component you can keep this.props.userName condition.

Comment: This way the HomePage component will update on further re-renders.